# Why WPF binding not work when bound to a tag of element itself

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

For the initial version, everything is good:

```xml
<ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter.Content>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WhateverConverter}">
            <Binding/>
            <Binding Path="DummyObject"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentPresenter.Content>
</ContentPresenter>
```

But after I binded the `Content` of `ContentPresenter` to `Tag` of the element, it don't work, and I wonder why this happens.

```xml
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ContentPresenter.Tag>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WhateverConverter}">
            <Binding/>
            <Binding Path="DummyObject"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentPresenter.Tag>
</ContentPresenter>
```

PS: I am using [NotifyTask](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/master/future/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs) to implement an async value converter, so I need to perform a so-called two-step converting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know that the `DataContext` of a `ContentPresenter` is the `Content` value. Therefore, the `Binding` in the second example does not behave as you expect (different `Binding.Source`).

In your second example, you set the `ContentPresenter.Content` to bind to its own `ContentPresenter.Tag` property. This makes `ContentPresenter.Tag` the `DataContext` of `ContentPresenter`. Now the `Binding` set on the `Tag` property has the `ContentPresenter.Tag` as `Binding` source (`DataContext`) and not the parent element's `DataContext`.

If you want to do what you are doing, you should replace the `ContentPresenter` with a `ContentControl`. `ContentControl` will not change its `DataContext`.

The `ContentPresenter` is primarily designed to be used inside the `ControlTemplate` of a `ContentControl`, where the `ContentPresenter` automatucally binds to the parent `ContentControl.Content` property. The persenter is *only* interested in the Content (to present it) and not the `DataContext` of the parent control. That's why the `ContentPresenter` has this special behavior regarding its `DataContext`. Maybe the name `ContentPresenter` makes a little more sense now.